# Arranging elements in a Relative Layout

Tags: android, layout

I have been trying to find the best way to do this for a while. What I want is something like this:

With the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

I've got this layout:

[image: The Layout I'm after]

The problem here is the margins are fixed amount of dpi. I'd like to get some sort of fluidity to this.

The way I would like this:

> Space above progress bar is separated in 3 equal parts, above the
>   first text, between the 1st and the 2nd texts and between the second
>   text and progress bar
>
> Indeterminate progress bar -  centered in the middle both vertically and horizontally.
>
> Space below progress bar is separated in 2 equal parts - between the progress bar and the button and between the button and the bottom
>   linear-layout.

Is there a way to do this relatively? I'd prefer doing it in a layout
 file, but I could also go for programming and spacing programmaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough layout with `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textView1"
   android:layout_above="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar1" />

<ProgressBar
  android:id="@+id/progressBar1" />

<Button
   android:id="@+id/button1"
   android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1" />

<TableRow
   android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
   android:weightSum="1.0">

<Button
   android:layout_weight="0.5" />

<Button
   android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</TableRow>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**NOTE:** With reference to `ProgressBar` in center you can arrange the upper and bottom layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressBar1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```